# How to catch and break on a Fortran 90 runtime error in GDB?

Tags: gdb, fortran

Is it possible to have Fortran 90 break at a runtime error in GDB? I show here a MWE for a simple routine *test.f90* which throws an out of bounds error:

```
program main
  implicit none
  integer              :: i
  integer, parameter   :: npt = 10
  real, dimension(npt) :: A
  real                 :: B
  !
  do i = 1,npt
     A(i) = i
  enddo
  B = A(npt+1)
  !
end program main
```

I compile as follows:

```
gfortran test.f90 -O0  -fbacktrace  -fbounds-check -g -Wall -w -o test.x
```

Which, mostly as expected, gives the backtrace here:

```
Error termination. Backtrace:
#0  0x7ffff7a0f2ed in ???
#1  0x7ffff7a0fed5 in ???
#2  0x7ffff7a102a7 in ???
#3  0x55555555480e in MAIN__
    at ~/test.f90:11
#4  0x555555554844 in main
    at ~/test.f90:13
```

When I run in GDB I set `catch catch` and `catch throw` catchpoints, but upon running GDB still lets the program terminate and I don't have frames to look at.

```
(gdb) catch catch
Catchpoint 1 (catch)
(gdb) catch throw
Catchpoint 2 (throw)
(gdb) r test.x
`~/test.x' has changed; re-reading symbols.
Starting program: ~/test.x test.x
warning: Probes-based dynamic linker interface failed.
Reverting to original interface.
[Inferior 1 (process 3769) exited normally]
(gdb) where
No stack.
(gdb) bt
No stack.
(gdb)
```

How can I get GDB to catch errors like this and start debugging from the culprit line? Obviously it's easy to identify useful break points in smaller scripts but in a larger legacy Fortran code it can save a ton of time and effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea if you can do it with `catch`, but you can try setting a break on `_gfortran_runtime_error_at`, then identify the culprit line from the backtrace (then set a breakpoint there, etc):

```
$ gdb -q ./test.x
Reading symbols from ./test.x...done.
(gdb) br _gfortran_runtime_error_at
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1030
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/test.x

Breakpoint 1, 0x00007ffff7d5e670 in _gfortran_runtime_error_at ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.5
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7d5e670 in _gfortran_runtime_error_at ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.5
#1  0x00005555555551fa in MAIN__ () at test.f90:11
(gdb) fram 1
#1  0x00005555555551fa in MAIN__ () at test.f90:11
11        B = A(npt+1)
```

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer since it does indeed work for Fortran with the gfortran compiler. Thanks! I'm wondering though where you found that specific runtime error function? How does a person find it if they're using a different compiler or language?

Comment: I have found it by entering `br ` and pressing TAB at the `(gdb) ` prompt; it's not a long list ;-)